# How can I make sure a url provided by the user is not a local path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security

I'm writhing a web application (ASP.Net MVC, C#) that require the user to provide urls to RSS or Atom Feed that I then read with the following code :

```
var xmlRdr = XmlReader.Create(urlProvidedByUserAsString);
var syndicFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlRdr);
```

While debugging my application I accidentally passed `/something/like/this` as an url and I got an exception telling me that `C:\something\like\this` can't be opened.

It looks like a user could provide a local path and my application would try to read it.

How can I make this code safe? It probably is not sufficient to check for `https://` or `http://` at the begining of the url, since the user could still enter something like `http://localhost/blah`. Is there any other way, maybe with the uri class to check if an url is pointing to the web?

**Edit:** I think I also need to prevent the user from entering adresses that would point to other machines on my network like this example: `http://192.168.0.6/` or `http://AnotherMachineName/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
new Uri(@"http://stackoverflow.com").IsLoopback
new Uri(@"http://localhost/").IsLoopback
new Uri(@"c:\windows\").IsLoopback
```

Comment: Great this seems to do it. However I just though of another case this might not handle. What if the user enter `http://anotherMachineNameOrIpOnMyNetwork/`?

Comment: Our company is usually blocked access from the DMZ to the LAN and to others DMZ servers (inside DMZ network) by default, allows access only to specific services and to the internet. Also you can resolve IPs for specified URL and check them for local network zone.

Comment: Of course everything should be firewalled, but still, I'd like to make sure I don't let any door opened.